# Cannot redeclare update_user_meta() when using custom wordpress php

Tags: php, wordpress, function

I am trying to update a user's last login time on a Wordpress site.

In the `functions.php` I am including a custom PHP file and in that file I have a function to update the user's metadata:

```
<?php

function update_user_meta($user_id, $meta_key, $meta_value, $prev_value = 
'') {
return update_metadata('user', $user_id, $meta_key, $meta_value, 
$prev_value);
}

echo "done";

?>
```

However this gives the error:

> Cannot redeclare update_user_meta()

Basically saying it's been declared here and can't be declared somewhere else.

Can anyone please help me as to why this is happening.

Comment: Try reinstalling the wordpress to the latest version.

Comment: Hey wordpress is an environment and this function might be defined in that environment which loads on every request ... so you can not re define functions with names already defined in wordpress core libs

Comment: Did you try Googling `update_user_meta`? The first result tells you that [Wordpress already has a function with that name](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_user_meta). One of the fundamental principles of programming is that you have have 2 functions (or variables, classes etc) with the same name.

Answer (score 0):

try to use a prefix for your function, change your code in this

```
<?php

function prefix_update_user_meta($user_id, $meta_key, $meta_value, $prev_value = 
'') {

return prefix_update_metadata('user', $user_id, $meta_key, $meta_value, 
$prev_value);

}

echo "done";

?>
```